# Function that processes touches

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an UITableView and I want to detect double touches on UITableViewCell.

I wanted to create a method, that will be called from the main app cycle and will process touches. (i.e. keep in memory time of 2 last touches and if the time is less than 0.5 of a second than it is a double touch)

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITouch already handles timing double-touches for you; it's in the `-tapCount` of the UITouch object. Look at [Event Delivery](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/EventHandling/EventHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW9) for some generic code for managing it.